# Simple Problem using Bayes Rule

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

This is Exercise 1 in Chapter 2 of the *Probabilistic Robotics* book by S. Thrun *etal*.

**Problem**. A robot uses a range sensor that can measure ranges from $1$m to $3$m. For simplicity, assume that actual ranges are distributed uniformly in this interval. Unfortunately, the sensor can be faulty. When it is faulty, it constantly outputs a range below $1$m, regardless of the actual range in the sensor's measurement cone. We know that the prior probability of a faulty sensor is $0.01$.

Suppose the robot queried its sensor $N$ times and every single time the measurement value is below $1$m. What is a posterior probability of a sensor fault as a function of $N$?

**Attempted Solution**. Let $\{X = 0\} = \{\text{sensor is faulty}\}$ and let $Z_k$ denote the $k^{\text{th}}$ sensor measurement. From the problem statement,

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
P(X = 0) &= 0.01,\\
P(Z_k < 1) &= 1/3,\\
P(Z_1 < 1, \ldots, Z_N < 1 | X = 0) &= 1.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

I assume that the sensor measurements are independent, i.e.,

\begin{equation}
P(Z_1 < 1, \ldots, Z_N < 1) = P(Z_1 < 1) \cdot \ldots \cdot  P(Z_N < 1) = (1/3)^N.
\end{equation}

The probability we are after is $P(X = 0 | Z_1 < 1, \ldots, Z_N < 1)$. Using Bayes rule:

\begin{align}
P(X = 0 | Z_1 < 1, \ldots, Z_N < 1) &= \frac{P(Z_1 < 1, \ldots, Z_N < 1 | X = 0) P(X = 0)}{P(Z_1 < 1, \ldots, Z_N < 1)} \\
&= \frac{1 \cdot 0.01}{(1/3)^N}.
\end{align}

This is not a probability since it is not bounded by 1. Where is the mistake?

Comment: Your rules are a bit hard to follow.  Did you mean to say that the probability  distribution for a *non-faulty* sensor  is uniform on $[0,3]$?

Comment: Sorry, I posted the exact problem statement as given in the book. Maybe, my probabilities in the attempted solution are wrong.

Comment: The problem can not be answered without clarifying that point.  It would, I think, be bizarre to assume that the distribution was uniform *for all* sensors.  Since we know it isn't uniform for the faulty ones, that would mean it couldn't be uniform for the other ones, so must be somehow contrived to offset the bias we get from the faulty ones.  I suggest assuming they meant to say that it is uniform on $[0.3]$ for the non-faulty ones only.

Comment: In any case, your computation does not make sense since you can not assume the events are independent.  Indeed, the events are all dependent on whether the chosen sensor is faulty or not

Comment: To illustrate the problem, consider a more extreme situation.  Say we have two coins, one of what can only come up $H$ and the other of which can only come up $T$.  Say you choose one uniformly at random and toss it a billion times.  The probability that you see a billion Heads is  still $\frac 12$.

Answer (score 1):

I will follow the OP's interpretation of the exercise. Then there are two ways the sensor can generate $N$ results below $1m$. Either the sensor is faulty, with probability $0.01$; or it is working with probability $0.99$ and measures $N$ values lower then $1m$, which has probability $(1/3)^N$.

In Bayesian statistics we take the sum of these two probabilities [$= 0.01 + 0.99*(1/3)^N$] and calculate the relative frequency of the desired result [faulty $= 0.01$]. If we do this, the posterior probability that the sensor is faulty is given by:

$$P = \frac {0.01} {0.01 + 0.99 * (1/3)^N}$$

This formula gives the correct result for $N = 0$. Furthermore if $N$ is very large the probability goes to $1$.